# p:treeTable and h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I got a `<p:treeTable>` that works perfectly as showcase, I open a dialog to see the detail of each node... the dialog have a `<h:selectOneMenu>` and it's not working. I don't know why, send me the error `"Target Unreachable"` but if I put the attribute  into a `<h:outputText>` it's working (it means that it's not null). What is happening?

```
<p:row>
    <p:column colspan="4" style="width:800px">
        <p:dialog id="edit" widgetVar="edit" header="Edit" showEffect="clip"
                  hideEffect="explode" position="center,center" width="520" modal="true" closable="false"
                  closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false" dynamic="true">
            <h:panelGrid width="100%">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column >
                        Name
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText value="#{levelBean.selectedLevel.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column >
                        Description
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText value="#{levelBean.selectedLevel.description}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column >
                        Level
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <!-- this its showing OK !! -->
                        <h:outputText value="#{levelBean.selectedLevel.id.idLevel}"/>
                        <!-- this mark target unreachable -->
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="cbo" style="width=200px"
                                         value="#{levelBean.selectedLevel.id.idLevel}" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{cboLevelBean.list}" var="levelEdit"
                                           itemValue="#{levelEdit.id.idNivel}"
                                           itemLabel="#{levelEdit.name}"
                                           />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:treeTable id="treeTableLevels" value="#{levelBean.root}" var="subLevel" style="width:800px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Levels
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="#{subLevel.object.levelName}">
                <h:outputText value="#{subNivel.object.nameSubLevel}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:24px">
                <p:commandLink update=":levelsForm:edit" oncomplete="PF('edit').show()" title="Level Detail" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{subLevel}" target="#{levelBean.selectedLevel}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please format the code in a way that makes it easier to read. Remove irrelevant rows/tags.
Also: `style="width=200px"` is syntactically incorrect. Use `style="width: 200px"`. Add the relevant code of your bean and whatever `selectedLevel` is.

Answer (score -1):

I fond the reason... I just put the selectonemenu into another form and it works.. but I don't know why.. can somebody explain?

```
<h:form id="someform">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cbo" style="width: 200px"
                     value="#{levelBean.selectedLevel.id.idLevel}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{cboLevelBean.list}" var="levelEdit"
                       itemValue="#{levelEdit.id.idNivel}"
                       itemLabel="#{levelEdit.name}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Anyway hope this help to others!

Comment: **another** form? or in **A** form? And now it is a p:selectOneMenu instead of h:...

Comment: but we cannot see nested forms anywhere... and if it succeeds now, you'll like run into problems soon. Better to fix the real issue... so next time please post a better example... And a dialog IN  a treetable is very inefficient. Put it outside the tree and update it where needed

Comment: in fact, the dialog its outside the treetable but in the same column, i really like to do it better, but if i dont put nested form the selectonemenu send target Unreachable :(

Comment: so your subject is wrong, the treetable has nothing to do with it? And what is around the outermost row? Please see [ask] and the part about an mcve. Create a full but minimal example that demonstrates the *real* problem